# Dynamic Event Generate - Jquery Event Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, all-in-one-event-calendar

I am using [Responsive Calendar](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/) Plug In which I need to dynamically create events.

How can I pass the arr event array as default event list to the plug in.

code is as follow.

[image]

Generated Event List is as follow

[image]

Comment: You can't do multi-line strings in JavaScript without "escaping" (backslash) the newline character. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: @David-SkyMesh : Thx and How can I generate the list dynamically any idea?

Comment: I'm not familary with this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `JSON.parse` on a a string that isn't really JSON.  It's just strings separated by colon.  Your string should have the `{ }` in it so that it will be parsed as a hash.

It should be `var str = '{ "2014..." : ... }'`

then `events : JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: yes correct but I need this way not really json (I have updated my question)

Comment: Why create a string only to parse it?  You don't need to jump through all those hoops.  Just have your PHP code write the map directly:

`var events = {};`

`events["2014-03-03"] = {"number" : 5,  }`

...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
    time: '2013-05',
    events: JSON.parse(arr),
});
```